# Add fanpage tab programatically using Facebook AP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anybody help me on how to publish a fanpage tab through the Facebook API?

I have the HTML for the fanpage tab, but i dont know how to publish it.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically you can do an HTTP Post to Graph API `PAGE_ID\tabs` passing in the post parameter of app_id with a value of your APP_ID.  You will need a app access token to do so.